# Is there a way to transform data in Python SQLAlchemy 2.0 prior to when using ORM to map the objects?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to transform incoming data (affiliations) as its being loaded into a mapped_column "affiliation_list" to comma separated python ordered list? Ex.: 'chemistry,biology'
Ten of thousands records can get inserted.

Incoming data (JSON):

```
[
  {
    "id": "djgjjgkgl",
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "e-mail": "jdoe@example.com",
    "affiliations": [
      {
        "affiliation": "chemistry"
      },
      {
        "affiliation": "biology"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Python to insert users:

```
....
session = Session(bind=c)
session.execute(
               insert(User),
               [ i for i in data ]
              )
session.commit()
session.close()
```

Model:

```
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

# declarative base class
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

# an example mapping using the base
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "USERS"

    username: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    firstName: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), name='first_name', nullable=False)
    lastName: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), name='last_name', nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), nullable=False)
    affiliations: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100),  name='affiliation_list', nullable=False)
```

I was looking in the SQLAlchemy documentation if this is possible and for examples but was not able to find something that would appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

I used Python list comprehension and def call in a separate call to loop through each user dict, extract the affiliations, join them into comma separated then update the user dict affiliations field:

```
def convert_affiliation(json_object):
   # Create temporary affiliation list
   aff_list = []
   # Loop over all the affiliations of a user
   for aff in json_object["affiliations"]:
          # Append our temporary affiliation list object with the sub-dictionary VALUE of KEY "affiliation"
          aff_list.append(aff["affiliation"])
          # Sort the affiliation list alphabetically
          aff_list.sort()
        #   print(aff_list)
          # Convert the list into a string
          aff_string = ','.join(aff_list)
        #   print(aff_string)
          # Now replace the original value of the KEY "affiliations" that was a sub-dictionary with our affiliation string
          json_object["affiliations"]=aff_string

   print(json.dumps(json_object, indent=2))
   return json_object
```